# Detect Cell Click in Mono TreeView

Tags: c#, mono, treeview, monodevelop, gtk#

I've got a tree view in my Mono application, I'm using GTK#. I want to be able to detect which Tree View cell the user has clicked in and get the data from that cell but can't find anything useful in the Mono Documentation.

Has anybody found a solution for this or any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please share your code to let us know what you have done so far.

Comment: There's no code worth sharing really, just a standard tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that by keeping a dictionary of objects keyed by their treepath in the treeview. E.g. something like:

```
IDictionary<string, MyType> thePathKeyedObjects = new Dictionary<string, MyType>();

Gtk.TreeStore _ts = new TreeStore (typeof(string));
foreach (MyType _t in _somelistofmytypes) {
    Gtk.TreeIter _it = _ts.AppendValues (_t.SomeTextForTheTreeView);
    thePathKeyedObjects.Add(_ts.GetPath (_it).ToString (), _t);
}
treeview.Model = _ts;

// and then later...

Gtk.TreeIter _it;
Gtk.TreeModel _mdl;
if (treeview.Selection.CountSelectedRows () > 0) {
    treeview.Selection.GetSelected (out _mdl, out _it);
    string _path = _mdl.GetPath (_it).ToString ();
    MyType _selected_t = thePathKeyedObjects[_path];
}
```